# How to customize the caption format for \lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, captions

I know how to customize the caption format of a `lstlisting` environment.

But how to do this if I used the `\lstinputlisting` command to import code?

My document contains the snippet below.

```
\begin{framed}
\lstinputlisting[label=samplecode,caption=sample code,language=python]{sample.py}
\end{framed}
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel the question is how to customize the font style of caption for` lstinputlisting` command

Comment: @MarcoDaniel for this case, i want to def the caption font inner frame as \small\tt

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the package `caption` for customization your output.

The modification can be done for `lstlisting` with the command `captionsetup`.

```
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={small,tt}}
```

Here the font is set to small and typewriter family is used.

Please have a closer look at the manual. Here a complete example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.py}
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("Hello!\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={small,tt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
\lstinputlisting[label=samplecode,caption=sample code,language=python]{sample.py}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much...i tried a whole day to find it...with your help it took 1 minute...